# Java 8 stream IllegalStateException

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to compute Prime numbers with Java8 streams, but I get into an IllegalStateException : stream has already been operated upon or closed.

This is my code :

```
package experimentations.chapter02;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class PrimesStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.iterate(0, e-> e+1).filter(PrimesStream::isPrime).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int i){
        if (i < 2) return false;
        Stream<Integer> stream =  Stream.iterate(2, e -> e+1);
        stream.limit(i - 2);
        return !stream.anyMatch(divisor -> i%divisor == 0);
    }

}
```

And this is the stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:229)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:449)
    at experimentations.chapter02.PrimesStream.isPrime(PrimesStream.java:14)
    at experimentations.chapter02.PrimesStream$$Lambda$2/918221580.test(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:529)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:516)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at experimentations.chapter02.PrimesStream.main(PrimesStream.java:7)
```

I have the feeling that this is because I am trying to apply a stream call into another, but  even with this thought, I don't know what is the simpliest workaround.

Comment: Please also notice that I should have limited the generator with i-2 numbers (edited) : otherwise I don't get any prime number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be chaining your stream methods, that will fix it, so your `isPrime` should be like:

```
return !Stream.iterate(2, e -> e + 1)
    .limit(i - 1)
    .anyMatch(divisor -> i % divisor == 0);
```

Comment: In fact I've just noticed that it is also possible to do without chaining : just storing each operation in different Stream<Integer>. But IMHO chaining is best in most cases.

Comment: I think, that's wrong. As far as I know it's never necessary to chain it. You just have to make sure, you call just one `terminal operation` on the stream.

Comment: @F.Böller If you don't chain, you *need* to store the resulting `IntStream` into itself, if you do not store it, everything is lost.

Comment: Ok, I tested it and you're right. But I still don't understand why. I had never had a problem with storing a stream in a local variable.

Comment: @F.Böller It is because any kind of stream instance is immutable, hence doing any other operations will not change anything to that stream. It will however **return** the new state, hence it does work when you save it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code that causes this exception.

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
 new Person("Bob", 17),
 new Person("Dave", 23),
 new Person("Joe", 32));

Stream<String> nameStream = people.stream()
 .filter(person -> person.getAge() > 21)
 .map(Person::getName);

nameStream.forEach(System.out::println);

// When stream values are gone, they are gone. Let’s try again: 
nameStream.forEach(System.out::println); 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:229)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
```

So, you can do only one operation at max on streams

Check [this](http://www.goldmansachs.com/gs-collections/presentations/2014_05_19_NY_Java_User_Group.pdf) for more about java8 features.